# Laravel resource controller additional route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In the Laravel documentation on resource controllers (http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers), there is a section titled "Adding Additional Routes To Resource Controllers".

It says to add a route before the resource route is declared.  So, in my route.php file I have this:

```
Route::get('faq/data');
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController');
```

After adding the first line show above, my /faq route no longer works.  I receive the following error:

```
Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Routing\Router::get(), called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 208 and defined
```

Is the documentation wrong?  How can I add an additional route to my resource controller?  I would like to add a route to `/faq/data` that will respond to a `GET` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the action, what should faq/data do?

```
Route::get('faq/data', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

or to a Controller method

```
Route::get('faq/data', 'MyController@showHelloWorld');
```